# Add alpha value when create image from MTLTexture

Tags: metal, metalkit

I am creating UIImage from current drawable texture as follows.

```
func createImageFromCurrentDrawable() ->(UIImage){

        let context = CIContext()
        let texture = metalView.currentDrawable!.texture


        let kciOptions = [kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!,
                          kCIContextOutputPremultiplied: true,
                          kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer: false] as [String : Any]

        let cImg = CIImage(mtlTexture: texture, options: kciOptions)!
        let cgImg = context.createCGImage(cImg, from: cImg.extent)!
        let uiImg =  UIImage(cgImage: cgImg)

        return uiImg
    }
```

but it adds alpha value to UIImage which is not appearing in the texture.Is there any solution to get rid of alpha?
here is captured texture image.

[image: texture image]

uiImage created from texture.

[image: uiImage]

Comment: What do you mean "it adds alpha value"? It's making portions of the image transparent that aren't transparent in the texture? Also, what is the value of the `framebufferOnly` property of your `MTKView`?

Comment: Sory for the confusion.I have added captured texture image & uiImage created from texture above.You may observe slightly alpha difference between two images.Btw my framebufferOnly property is set to be false.

Comment: Is the yellow part of the texture or just to illustrate transparency? The images themselves don't have transparency. That may be an RGB vs. sRGB issue. What's the pixel format of the texture? Try specifying a dictionary of options, mapping `CIImageOption.colorSpace` to your `MTKView`'s `colorspace` or, if that's `nil`, to `NSNull`.

Comment: I have specified a dictionary of options to map ciimage options.(check updated code above).But the issue exists.Btw CGColorSpace is .sRGB but my renderPipelineDescriptor's pixelFormat is .bgra8Unorm. So is there anything to do with this or possible way to make  CGColorSpace into .bgra8Unorm format?

Comment: Did you try other colorspace values? `NSNull` as I suggested, or `.genericRGB` or `.genericRGBLinear`?

Comment: yes.But it won't work unfortunately